# KIE RuleServicesClient returns empty response

Tags: drools, kie, kie-server

I receive successful but EMPTY result from Drools Execution Server when call from Java application using `RuleServiceClient` although REST call from Postman returns expected result.

My question: what is incorrect in my Java code?

Please find details below.

I created sample rule (if field `Message.MyField == 1` then set this field to `400`) and I was able to fire it on KIE Execution Server using Postmen:

POST Request to `http://SERVER:8080/kie-server-webc/services/rest/server/containers/instances/kie-container`:

```
{
    "lookup": "defaultStatelessKieSession",
    "commands": [{
        "insert": {
            "object": {
                "Message": {
                    "myField": 1
                }
            },
            "disconnected": false,
            "out-identifier": "Message",
            "return-object": true,
            "entry-point": "DEFAULT"
        }
    }, {
        "fire-all-rules": {
            "max": -1,
            "out-identifier": null
        }
    }]
}
```

Response (please note `"myField": 500`):

```
{
  "type": "SUCCESS",
  "msg": "Container kie-container successfully called.",
  "result": {
    "execution-results": {
      "results": [
        {
          "key": "Message",
          "value": {
            "bnym.test1.Message": {
              "myField": 500
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "facts": [
        {
          "key": "Message",
          "value": {
            "org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle": {
              "external-form": "0:1:1208207159:1208207159:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:myProj.test1.Message"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My Java client code borrowed from tutorial is:

```
public class Message{
    public Integer myField; 
}
```

. . .

```
private static String URL = "http://SERVER:8080/kie-server-webc/services/rest/server";    
private static final String USER = "user";  
private static final String PASSWORD = "pwd";
```

. . .

```
public void transform() throws Exception {
    Message m = new Message();
    m.myField = 1;

    KieServicesConfiguration config = KieServicesFactory.newRestConfiguration(URL, USER, PASSWORD);  
    config.setMarshallingFormat(MarshallingFormat.JSON);  
    kieServicesClient = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(config); 

    RuleServicesClient rulesClient = kieServicesClient.getServicesClient(RuleServicesClient.class);  
    KieCommands commandsFactory = KieServices.Factory.get().getCommands();  

    Command<?> insert = commandsFactory.newInsert(m);  
    Command<?> fireAllRules = commandsFactory.newFireAllRules(); 
    Command<?> batchCommand = commandsFactory.newBatchExecution(Arrays.asList(insert, fireAllRules));  //0
    ServiceResponse<String> executeResponse = rulesClient.executeCommands("kie-container", batchCommand);

    if(executeResponse.getType() == ResponseType.SUCCESS) {  
        System.out.println("Commands executed with success! Response: ");  
        System.out.println(executeResponse.getResult());  
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Commands executed with success! Response: 
{
  "results" : [ ],
  "facts" : [ ]
}
```

My question: what is incorrect in my Java code so result is empty?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following command:

```
Message m = new Message();
m.myField = 1;
Command<?> insert = commandsFactory.newInsert(m,  "Message",true, "DEFAULT");
```

This is equivalent to the json request you are using:

```
"insert": {
        "object": {
            "Message": {
                "myField": 1
            }
        },
        "out-identifier": "Message",
        "return-object": true,
        "entry-point": "DEFAULT"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest turn on debug logging for the client to see the sent request and compare it to your other one to find what's not correct with it.

For whatever logging system your app is using, set this logger to DEBUG (or just set everything to DEBUG if that's better for you):
org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using stateless session, then you should create a stateless session, follow the example code:

```
public static StatelessKieSession getStatelessKieSession() {
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
    StatelessKieSession kSession = kContainer.newStatelessKieSession("defaultStatelessKieSession");
    return kSession;
}

public void runRulesStateless(List<Object> objects) {
    getStatelessKieSession().execute(objects);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    runRulesStateless(Arrays.asList(new Object[] { new Message() }));
}
```

If you want a differente stateless session, you can configure in a kmodule.xml